# What is the scope of action on date_default_timezone_set in PHP?

Tags: php, date, timezone

What is the scope of action on date_default_timezone_set in PHP?

I mean if I use:

```
function foo()
{
date_default_timezone_set('valid string'); /* where valid string is a valid date_default_timezone_set parameter */
echo (date('bla bla'));
}
```

after the use of foo() the dates will get back to normal/default time zone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the scope is the lifetime of the executing script. Typically you call `date_default_timezone_set` once (on script initialization) and then just forget about it.